# Apply function on dataframe by specific group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
dist   id daytime  season 
3  1.11     Name1     day    summer   
4  2.22     Name2     night  spring   
5  3.33     Name1     day    winter   
6  4.44     Name3     night  fall
```

I want of summary of `dist`by some specific columns in my dataframe.

So far I used a custom function:

```
summary <- function(x){df %>%                               
    group_by(x) %>% 
    summarize(min = min(dist),
              q1 = quantile(dist, 0.25),
              median = median(dist),
              mean = mean(dist),
              q3 = quantile(dist, 0.75),
              max = max(dist))}
```

And applied it to  any specific column I wanted at the moment:

```
summary_ID <- path.summary(id)
```

I tried it a few weeks ago and would get something like this>

```
  id       min    q1 median  mean    q3   max
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Name1   0     17.8   310.   788. 1023. 5832.
 2 Name2   0     31.7   284.   570.  744. 9578.
 3 Name3   0     17.0   325.   721. 1185. 5293.
 4 Name4   0     11.9   197.   530.  865. 3476.
 5 Name5   0     24.5    94.9  617.  966. 9567.
```

When I try it now I get an error:

```
Error in `group_by()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
✖ Column `x` is not found.
```

What changed and how do I get around the issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we may use `{{}}` if the input is unquoted

```
path_summary <- function(dat, x){
  dat %>%                               
    group_by({{x}}) %>% 
    summarize(min = min(dist),
              q1 = quantile(dist, 0.25),
              median = median(dist),
              mean = mean(dist),
              q3 = quantile(dist, 0.75),
              max = max(dist))
}
```

-testing

```
> path_summary(df, id)
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  id      min    q1 median  mean    q3   max
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Name1  1.11  1.66   2.22  2.22  2.78  3.33
2 Name2  2.22  2.22   2.22  2.22  2.22  2.22
3 Name3  4.44  4.44   4.44  4.44  4.44  4.44
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(dist = c(1.11, 2.22, 3.33, 4.44), id = c("Name1", 
"Name2", "Name1", "Name3"), daytime = c("day", "night", "day", 
"night"), season = c("summer", "spring", "winter", "fall")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("3", 
"4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: It returns this warning  `Warning messages:
1: In min(dist) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(dist) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: @eldritchmayo can you show the warning message

Comment: And I am still curious why it worked before and dosen't now.

Comment: @eldritchmayo sorry, not get any warning with the data you showed.  Please check the input and output I got

Comment: @eldritchmayo also check your `str(df)` .  Is the `dist` column `numeric`?

Comment: My appologies, I was playing around with the dataframe to fix the issue and accidentaly reduced it to empty. It works fine now. Thank you!